# Android: RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. I am having trouble retrieving data from firebase and displaying it.

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I really don't know where I am going wrong. According to the documentation I am doing everything right. I am doubtful if it's happening just because I am using TabbedActivity and dealing with fragments, but still I don't know how it's wrong.
Please look into the code and help me out. I have been struggling a lot to achieve this task of retrieving and displaying data from FIREBASE. 
And being a beginner in this, it's quite hard for me to figure it out.

MainActivity.Java

```
    package com.example.souravkumar.sqaurewallpapers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    int count=0;
    public FloatingActionButton mAddImage;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    public DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String stringUri;
    Long date;

    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mAddImage = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addImage);

        mAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Wallpapers").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    //Adding image to the database
                    stringUri= downloadUrl.toString();
                    date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    addImageToDatabase (stringUri, date);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void addImageToDatabase(String downloadUrl, Long date){
     image_details id= new image_details(downloadUrl, date);
        String key = mDatabase.push().getKey();
        mDatabase.child(key).child("URL").setValue(id.getUrl());
        mDatabase.child(key).child("Date").setValue(id.getDate());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        GridView gridView;



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "POPULAR";
                case 1:
                    return "RECENT";
                case 2:
                    return "PROFILES";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Popular.Java

```
package com.example.souravkumar.sqaurewallpapers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Sourav Kumar on 11/3/2017.
 */

public class popular extends FragmentActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details,BlogViewHolder>(
                image_details.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                myRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, image_details model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setUrl(model.getUrl());
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    }


    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
            textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        public void setDate(Long date) {
            textView.setText(date.toString());
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .resize(50, 50)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }

}
```

image_details.Java

```
package com.example.souravkumar.sqaurewallpapers;

/**
 * Created by Sourav Kumar on 10/29/2017.
 */

public class image_details {
    String url;
    Long date;


    image_details(){}

    public image_details(String url, Long date){
        this.url = url;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

fragment_popular.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.souravkumar.sqaurewallpapers.popular">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

individual_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:id="@+id/date"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Are you sure myRef isn't null?

Comment: How do I check it? System.println?

Comment: You would use Log.d("DEBUG","" + myRef);

Comment: Hold a sec, checking

Comment: also try removing the this line "recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)". If that doens't work try "recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);"

Comment: @WadeWilson nothing worked. Yes, it is connecting to the database. but no  displaying of data is taking place.

Comment: are `String url;
    Long date;` the same in the database(same word, capital letter..)

Comment: @PeterHaddad The structure of the database is like this. Key--> (Date:......, URL:...... ) Both are under the random key generated.

Comment: @PeterHaddad How does variable names matter anyways?

Comment: Just debug it, add in the  database  and see if anything is getting seen on your phone then change the variable name in the model class to be the same as im database

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have tried all possible ways to debug, didn't get any output on logcat. Pls tell some specific thing to try.